# How to add margin in dp on dynamically generated views in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I have added 2 views from xml in constraint layout, Now i need to add new view below the view created from xml

This is what i do to add new view

```
//leftMargin calculation
int topMargin= Utils.pxToDp(20);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
constraintLayout.addView(imageView);

ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(constraintLayout);
set.constrainWidth(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);

set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, eventsViewPager.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, topMargin);
```

I am defining margin `20dp` here, but it just adds a thin line over the view, and if i use margin around 400, then it gives me the desired result, there must be some mistake in conversion may be that i am making here.

**This is how i convert values from `px` to `dp`**

```
public static int pxToDp(int px){
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert DP to pixel and not viceversa, use `TypedValue` for that like this:

```
int marginTopDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, 
                              getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```